# Invoke-WebRequest: Accept a cookie

Tags: powershell

I'm updating the title of this, because I am sure it is to do with accepting cookies, recording it in the session variable and passing it to the next web request in the websession. Although I may be closer, I still can't do it.

Regarding the following URI: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix
Assuming there is no cookie, one is presented with two buttons:

- I Accept
- I do not accept

Using PowerShell's Invoke-WebRequest, how do I "click" I Accept?

Using various examples from around the net, I've been trying variations of the following:

```
$baseUri = "https://support.microsoft.com"
$uri = $baseURI +"/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix"

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -SessionVariable sv

$Response.forms[0].Action #= /en-us/Hotfix/KbHotfix

$Form = $Response.forms[0]
$form.fields["accept"] = "Accept"

$MainPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($baseUri + $Form.Action) -Method
$form.Method -Body $form.fields -WebSession $sv
$MainPage
```

But when I execute "$MainPage.forms[0].Fields, the resulting values are "I Do Not Accept" or "I Accept" which to me, suggests it has not "clicked I Accept.

Do I need call the onClick event?

Any suggestions / example would be gratefully received.

(PowerShell V5)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an extra cookie:

```
$cookie = New-Object System.Net.Cookie("hotfixEulaCookie", "1", "/", "support.microsoft.com")
$sv.Cookies.Add($cookie)
```

I think you do not even need the first request. Just create a `WebRequestSession` variable and add that single cookie to it.

How to solve such problems in future:

- Use the web browser's F12 developer tools to see the exchange and the cookies
- Look at the form's HTML code and the scripts
- Play with the HTTP requests in Fiddler's request composer

This is how the form looks in HTML:

```
<input class="eulabutton" id="cancel" name="cancel" onclick="onHotfixEulaAction('cancel', '/kb//')" type="button" value="I Do Not Accept" ms.cmptyp="button" ms.cmpnm="noacpt" ms.title="Donot Accept" ms.interactiontype="22">
<input class="eulabutton" id="accept" name="accept" onclick="onHotfixEulaAction('accept', '/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=&amp;kbln=')" type="button" value="I Accept" ms.cmptyp="button" ms.cmpnm="acpt" ms.title="Accept" ms.interactiontype="22">
```

We search for onHotfixEulaAction and find

https://az623152.vo.msecnd.net/cdnresources/2.38/common/script/gsfx/default.js

```
function onHotfixEulaAction(arg, url) {
    setcookieval("hotfixEulaCookie", (arg == "accept") ? '1' : '0', '', false);
    document.location.href = url;
}
```